# How to override logging settings when running azure Functions locally?

Tags: azure-functions

Logging settings for Azure Functions are defined in the [host.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging). Currently the run-time [filters-out most of the logging categories](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4345), so exclusions need to be added to the `host.json` file. But this file is applied in all environments which results in a single logging configuration for all of them.

How to keep a single definition for production environment in `host.json`, then to override it when running locally without editing that file every time?

In ASP.Net Core, we use the `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.{environment}.json` file to achieve this aim but those are not supported out of the box by Azure Functions.
The equivalent of `appsettings.Development.json` file for Azure Functions is `local.settings.json`, but it does not support any configuration related to logging. The [`Host` node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) it contains is not related in any way to `host.json` file content.

I also haven't found any easy way to do it programmatically from `FunctionsStartup` without breaking all/some of Azure Functions DI setup...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I override the host settings of my azure function locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949260/how-can-i-override-the-host-settings-of-my-azure-function-locally)

Comment: [See here for information on this on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to load in and customize host.json files via environment variables (`local.settings.json` locally or application settings in the cloud).  We just don't yet document it very good.  You can see details in this comment:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4575#issuecomment-511570111

For example if I wanted to set an environment variable to change the routePrefix, the host.json would look like

```
{
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": "test",
        }
    }
}
```

But I could do this with an environment variable with the following format:

`AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__http__routePrefix` with the value of `test`

I made a note to add official docs on this

Comment: I tried this for logging by adding an entry in `Values` as `"Logging__LogLevel__MyCategory": "Trace"`, but it did not work (adding the same setting to `host.json` did work but this is what I want to avoid). Are you sure logging configurations are properly loaded from environment variables?

Comment: Would be AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__LogLevel__MyCategory

Comment: Rahhhh what a dumb! sorry about this! Going to retest it right away

Comment: Just to make sure I'm grokking this; in order to GET that value, in case you needed to in your code, would it be `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__LogLevel__MyCategory");` ?