# How can I override the host settings of my azure function locally?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, settings

Say you have a host.json file like this:

```js
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 16,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But you wish to override the setting locally in `local.settings.json` or in the settings for a given environment on Azure. Is it possible, and how do you do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible, but poorly documented. [Fabio Cavalcante](https://github.com/fabiocav) describes it in a comment [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4575#issuecomment-511570111).

You simply have to prefix the setting with `AzureFunctionsJobHost` in your `local.settings.json` file (or on Azure) like this:

```js
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:Extensions:ServiceBus:MessageHandlerOptions:MaxConcurrentCalls": 32,
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:Extensions:ServiceBus:MessageHandlerOptions:MaxAutoRenewDuration": "00:10:00"
  }
}
```

You can also use double underscore (`__`) instead of colon (`:`).

Comment: It'a actually [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values)

Comment: Great. That is, however, documentation that came after this question. But nice to see they've fixed it.

Comment: Yep sure that's true, just pointing out that "poorly documented" is a little out of date

Comment: That said, this is currently broken https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2216